# Unable to access files outside Wordpress directory due to htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I currently use the following rules on my wordpress multisites .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This allows me to access the Wordpress Multsite as normal. However, I am unable to see any files that are not apart of Wordpress e.g. license.txt in the root directory. Instead I get a Wordpress 'page not found' error.

By removing the comment tag from this line:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
```

I can see file as normal, however this stops the multsite from working. I just get a white page.

Any advice appreciated.